# Warning: mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link resource supplied

Tags: php, html, mysql, warnings

I'm facing an issue with my php code. I get the error "Warning: mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link resource supplied in C:\wamp\www\Tuto sessions\register.php on line 75".

This register.php page is a form : new users are supposed to fill the fields to create a new account.

I get this error when I type a login, 2 identical passwords but a wrong email address such as admin@.com.

Could you help ? Thanks in advance !

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html xmls="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<title>Créer un compte</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if ($_POST['registerbtn']) {
$getuser = $_POST['user'];
$getemail = $_POST['email'];
$getpass = $_POST['pass'];
$getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

if ($getuser) {
    if ($getemail) {
        if ($getpass) {
            if ($getretypepass) {
                if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                    if ((strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {
                        require("./connect.php");

                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'");
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 0) {
                        }                           
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$getemail'");
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 0) {

                            $password = md5(md5("sjtmbcp".$password."sjtmbcp"));
                            $date = date("F d, Y");
                            $code = md5(rand());

                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                '', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date')");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                            if ($numrows == 1) {
                                $site = "http://localhost/Tuto%20sessions";
                                $webmaster = "Lamplistr <admin@lamplistr.com>";
                                $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                $subject = "Activez votre compte";
                                $message = "Bonjour, \n nous vous remercions de vous être inscrit sur Lamplistr. Cliquez sur le lien ci-dessous pour activer votre compte : \n ";
                                $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code \n";
                                $message .= "Vous devez activer votre compte pour pouvoir l'utiliser.";

                                if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                    $errormsg = "Votre compte a été créé avec succès. Vous devez l'activer en cliquant sur le lien qui vous a été envoyé à l'adresse <b>$getemail</b>.";
                                    $getuser = "";
                                    $getemail = "";
                                }
                                else
                                    $errormsg = "Une erreur est survenue. Votre email d'activation n'a pas été envoyé.";
                            }

                            else
                                $errormsg = "Une erreur est survenue. Votre compte n'a pas été créé.";
                        }
                        else
                            $errormsg = "L'email que vous avez choisi est déjà utilisé.";
                    }
                    else
                        $errormsg = "Le nom d'utilisateur que vous avez choisi est déjà utilisé.";

                        mysql_close();
                    }
                    else
                        $errormsg = "Vos mots de passe ne sont pas identiques.";
                }
                else
                    $errormsg = "Vous devez retaper votre mot de passe.";
            }
            else
                $errormsg = "Vous devez taper votre mot de passe.";
        }
        else
            $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer un mot de passe.";
    }
    else
        $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer une adresse email.";
}

else
    $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer un nom d'utilisateur.";


$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Login :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Email :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' /></td>           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='pass' value='' /></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Retype your password :</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Valider' /></td>         
    </tr>
</table>
</form>";


echo $form;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, your source code hurts me.

Comment: As per the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php `mysql_close($link);`

Comment: Ahah, why that @CharlotteDunois ? I'm just beginning php. But if it hurts you, you can probably help me ;)

Comment: First of all, stop using the deprecated mysql extension and get started with PDO. Don't simply check post values with `if($variable) {` make use of `empty()` if it's empty or not. Validate the email with `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` and not with some length and position check. http://php.net/pdo http://php.net/empty http://php.net/filter_var

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd have to show us this line. Generally, though, using [mysql_close()](http://www.php.net/mysql_close) isn't needed - the connection is automatically closed when the script has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are openning you connection into your IF statement, so you don't have a valid link resource into your else statemente, try to move it into your IF statement as well:

```
<body>

<?php

if ($_POST['registerbtn']) {
$getuser = $_POST['user'];
$getemail = $_POST['email'];
$getpass = $_POST['pass'];
$getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

if ($getuser) {
    if ($getemail) {
        if ($getpass) {
            if ($getretypepass) {
                if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                    if ((strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {
                        require("./connect.php");

                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'");
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 0) {
                        }                           
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$getemail'");
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 0) {

                            $password = md5(md5("sjtmbcp".$password."sjtmbcp"));
                            $date = date("F d, Y");
                            $code = md5(rand());

                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                '', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date')");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                            if ($numrows == 1) {
                                $site = "http://localhost/Tuto%20sessions";
                                $webmaster = "Lamplistr <admin@lamplistr.com>";
                                $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                $subject = "Activez votre compte";
                                $message = "Bonjour, \n nous vous remercions de vous être inscrit sur Lamplistr. Cliquez sur le lien ci-dessous pour activer votre compte : \n ";
                                $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code \n";
                                $message .= "Vous devez activer votre compte pour pouvoir l'utiliser.";

                                if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                    $errormsg = "Votre compte a été créé avec succès. Vous devez l'activer en cliquant sur le lien qui vous a été envoyé à l'adresse <b>$getemail</b>.";
                                    $getuser = "";
                                    $getemail = "";
                                }
                                else
                                    $errormsg = "Une erreur est survenue. Votre email d'activation n'a pas été envoyé.";
                            }

                            else
                                $errormsg = "Une erreur est survenue. Votre compte n'a pas été créé.";
                        }
                        else {
                            $errormsg = "L'email que vous avez choisi est déjà utilisé.";
                        }

                        mysql_close();
                    }
                    else
                        $errormsg = "Le nom d'utilisateur que vous avez choisi est déjà utilisé.";
                    }
                    else
                        $errormsg = "Vos mots de passe ne sont pas identiques.";
                }
                else
                    $errormsg = "Vous devez retaper votre mot de passe.";
            }
            else
                $errormsg = "Vous devez taper votre mot de passe.";
        }
        else
            $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer un mot de passe.";
    }
    else
        $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer une adresse email.";
}

else
    $errormsg = "Vous devez entrer un nom d'utilisateur.";


$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Login :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Email :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' /></td>           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='pass' value='' /></td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Retype your password :</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Valider' /></td>         
    </tr>
</table>
</form>";


echo $form;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Vinibarr, it almost works ! I don't have this mysql error anymore, but now I have the message "Une erreur est survenue. Votre compte n'a pas été créé.", but I don't know why I get this !

Comment: You have to pass the variable that you would like to close the connection. I would recommend you to use PDO that is a lot of easier and safer to use.

For what you have you could make a test like opeening you connection, and closing it passing this created variable. Something like this:

    <?php
    $open = mysql_connect(...);
    mysql_close($open);
    ?>

So you'll be able to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks Charlotte ! I'll take a look at this !

Comment: @ZeFifi Probably because (or contributing factor) you're not entering the password set from your variable `$getpass` and using `$password` instead. You can try changing `$password = md5(md5("sjtmbcp".$password."sjtmbcp"));` to `$password = md5(md5("sjtmbcp".$getpass."sjtmbcp"));` but not 100% sure that will work, but you can try it. An important note: I highly suggest you do not use MD5 for password storage, it's old and considered broken; it dates to 1992 and should not be used.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I get a new error :) I have to review my classics, I was sure MD5 was safe. I'm gonna take a look at PDO to have a fresh and clean code. Thank you all for your kind assistance !